# List Html for Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I have a HTML content list and would like to render it as tabs.
My code:

```
<div class="itemExtraFields">
<ul id="conteudo">
        <li class="even typeTextarea group1">
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Contéudo:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><p>teste</p></span>
        </li>
        <li class="odd typeTextarea group1">
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Público-alvo:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><p>teste</p></span>
        </li>
        <li class="even typeTextarea group1">
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Tutor:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><p>teste</p></span>
        </li>
        <li class="odd typeTextarea group1">
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Diferenciais:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><p>teste</p></span>
        </li>
        <li class="even typeTextarea group1">
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Depoimentos:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><p>teste</p></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want the class "itemExtraFieldsLabel" to display as the title of the tab and the class "itemExtraFieldsValue" to be the content.
How could I make that with jQuery or just plain javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Use http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: HTML is created by Joomla 3, I do not have to distinguish the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
     <style type="text/css">

         .itemExtraFields {
             margin: 10px;
         }

         .itemExtraFields ul {
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
         }

         .itemExtraFields li {
             display: inline-block;
             border: 1px solid #CCC;
             border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
             border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
             padding: 5px 15px;
             cursor: pointer;
             background: #CCC;
         }

         .itemExtraFieldsValue {
             display: none;
         }

         .container {
             border-top: 1px solid #333;
         }

         .active {
             background: #FFF !important;
         }

     </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="itemExtraFields">
<ul id="conteudo">
        <li class="even typeTextarea group1">
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Contéudo:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><p>teste1</p></span>
        </li>
        <li class="odd typeTextarea group1">
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Público-alvo:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><p>teste2</p></span>
        </li>
        <li class="even typeTextarea group1">
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Tutor:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><p>teste3</p></span>
        </li>
        <li class="odd typeTextarea group1">
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Diferenciais:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><p>teste4</p></span>
        </li>
        <li class="even typeTextarea group1">
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel">Depoimentos:</span>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><p>teste5</p></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.itemExtraFields').append('<div class="container"></div>');
        var arrContent = $('.itemExtraFieldsValue:first');      
        $('.container').html($(arrContent[0]).html());
        $('.itemExtraFields ul li:first').addClass('active');

        $('.itemExtraFields ul li').click(function () {
            $('.container').html($(this).find('.itemExtraFieldsValue').html());
            $('.itemExtraFields ul li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });

    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito!